# Communication with mutiple docker-compose.yml which are in different bridge network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Suppose i have multiple docker-compose.yml with some static ip's and i want to connect them with each other without exposing the ports. Which network type would be suitable to achieve that overlay or bridg?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you don't connect docker-compose.yml files, you connect services defined in the compose file(s).

If you'll run the compose files on the same docker host machine, you can create a network and reference that network in your compose files as external network [like so](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network):

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my-pre-existing-network
```

If you run your compose files on different docker host machines and don't want to expose ports to the outside world, you can configure your firewall to allow connections only from specific IPs to these ports, configure your application to respond only to specific IPs, [bind the Docker ports to specific IPs](https://runnable.com/docker/binding-docker-ports) or create SSH tunnels between the machines (although the SSH port should be exposed)